# Getting ID of inserte row in Oracle, using sequence and trigger to insert the id

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to get the vale of an "autoincrement" column in Oracle db. To create that column I use a sequence and a trigger.

Creation script:

```
create table SD_LOG (
    ID_SD_LOG       number(19) primary key,
    LOG_DATE        timestamp(3) default systimestamp NOT NULL,
    MODULE          nvarchar2(15) NOT NULL,
    INSTANCE        number(5) NOT NULL,
    REMOTE_ADDR     nvarchar2(39) NOT NULL,
    USERNAME        nvarchar2(30) NOT NULL,
    USER_AGENT      nvarchar2(1024) NOT NULL,
    HTTP_METHOD     nvarchar2(8) NOT NULL,
    HTTP_REQ_URL    nvarchar2(1024) NOT NULL,
    HTTP_STATUS     number(5),
    ERROR           nvarchar2(100),
    DETAILS         clob
);

/

-- Generate ID using sequence and trigger
create sequence SD_LOG_seq start with 1 increment by 1;

create or replace trigger SD_LOG_seq_tr
 before insert on SD_LOG for each row
 when (new.ID_SD_LOG is null)
begin
 select SD_LOG_seq.nextval into :new.ID_SD_LOG from dual;
end;
/
```

Every time I make an insert I need to get the ID_SD_LOG created value for later row update.

I followed some other questions but for some reason the statement I am trying is failing with:

> SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword

This is the statement I'm trying to run (insert alone, without the 'RETURNING...' works just fine):

```
INSERT INTO SD_LOG 
(MODULE, INSTANCE, REMOTE_ADDR, USERNAME, USER_AGENT, HTTP_METHOD, HTTP_REQ_URL) 
VALUES
('modulename', '1', '192.168.0.1', 'User Name', 'blah blah blah blah', 'POST', '/page?query=1234567890')
RETURNING ID_SD_LOG INTO gen_id;
```

Any idea why am I getting that error? Or any other way to do this without using a procedure?

Comment: How are you running this query? From within a PL/SQL block? Because (regrettably) the `RETURNING` clause is a PL/SQL language feature in Oracle, not a SQL language feature.

Comment: Works fine for me if I run the query in a PL/SQL block, with `gen_id` defined as `NUMBER`. As @LukasEder asks, what's the context in which you're executing your INSERT...RETURNING... statement?

Comment: @LukasEder ah... I'm testing these statements in Oracle SQL Developer, which I'm guessing uses SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`RETURNING`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/returninginto_clause.htm#LNPLS01354) clause is a PL/SQL language feature. You cannot use it from ordinary SQL contexts, such as SQL Developer scripts, SQL*Plus, or JDBC statements. That's very unfortunate of course. [There's an idea on this Oracle ideas platform that can be upvoted, to fix this](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/21711).

You can, however, wrap your statement in an anonymous block, to get back to the PL/SQL context:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  gen_id SD_LOG.ID_SD_LOG%TYPE;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO SD_LOG 
  (MODULE, INSTANCE, REMOTE_ADDR, USERNAME, USER_AGENT, HTTP_METHOD, HTTP_REQ_URL) 
  VALUES
  ('modulename', '1', '192.168.0.1', 'User Name', 'blah blah blah blah', 'POST', '/page?query=1234567890')
  RETURNING ID_SD_LOG INTO gen_id;

  dbms_output.put_line(gen_id);
END;
/
```